# Jquery parent class selector

Tags: jquery, css

i have this
HTML

```
<label class="rlabel">First Name</label>    
<input class="rinput" type="text" placeholder="Fisrt Name" required />     
<label class="rlabel">Last Name</label>    
<input class="rinput" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />
```

CSS

```
.rlabel{opacity:0;  }
```

Jquery

```
$('.rinput').focus(function(){
        $(this).parent('.rlabel').css({'opacity':'1'});
        })
```

I want to make the parent class "rlabel" of this class "rinput" opacity 1 by jquery when i focus .

I tried the following :

```
$('.rinput').focus(function(){
        $(this).parents('.rlabel').css({'opacity':'1'});
        })
```

and

```
$('.rinput').focus(function(){
        $(this).parent('.rlabel').css({'opacity':'1'});
        })
```

and

```
$('.rinput').focus(function(){
        $(this).closest('.rlabel').css({'opacity':'1'});
        })
```

and

```
$('.rinput').focus(function(){
        $(this).parents().css({'opacity':'1'});
        })
```

Comment: try with `.prev()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You friend here is `.prev()` since the `label` is not a parent element to the `input`

```js
$('.rinput').focus(function() {
  $(this).prev('.rlabel').css({
    'opacity': '1'
  });
})
```

```css
.rlabel {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="rlabel">First Name</label>
<input class="rinput" type="text" placeholder="Fisrt Name" required />
<label class="rlabel">Last Name</label>
<input class="rinput" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,  I thought that the above element always is PARENT.

Comment: @RazenKellesly Parent is only if the object is inside of another